# Run cmd command from vb.net button

Tags: .net, vb.net, cmd

I have a simple question that i haven't been able to find the answer to.
I have a cmd line program (tap). i have set the path in the environment variable so i can run it from the cmd prompt without issue.

it looks like this:

> tap -u load file1 file2

how do i run this via button click in vb.net?

Here's what i have so far...

```
  Private Sub Flash_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles flashBundle.Click
        'If (String.Compare(imageTextBox.Text, "") <> 0) And (String.Compare(radioTextBox.Text, "") <> 0) Then
        Dim pi As New ProcessStartInfo("C:\p4\main\armos\common\tools\tap.exe")
        pi.WorkingDirectory = "C:\p4\main\armos\common\tools\"
        pi.Arguments = ("-u load " + imageTextBox.Text + " " + radioTextBox.Text)
        Process.Start(pi)
        'End If
    End Sub
```

The cmd window flashes and the program doesn't execute.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you wrote the tap program? if yes, my suggestion is to add a `readLine` at the end of it so the cmd window will not flash and you will be able to see the output..

Comment: @udidu unfortunately i did not write it and it is an executable. My first thought was to open it and add a 'Pause' to the end of the file, if it were a standard batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

```
pi.UseShellExecute = True
```

If you want to launch this process via command line. The way you are doing it now is launching it like you were double clicking it.

Kind of related - stackoverflow.com/q/2382683/16391

Comment: @StingyJack...Thank You! Exactly what i needed!